# What could cause a retrofit, okhttp get request to not call its onResponse() or onFailure() method?

Tags: android, request, retrofit2, response, okhttp

I'm working on a mobile app that needs to download data from a server. It worked perfectly but after some changes were made to the server the GET request from Retrofit stopped working.
It makes the request successfully and sometimes it even gets a succesful response, but it never calls neither the onResponse() nor the onFailure() methods, so the app just stays there hanging.

Basically there are 2 scenarios:

1. The request is done correctly. The response is received by Okhttp and it prints the content, but it ends with a message ("read: Unexpected EOF!"). After that the app stops working. It doesn't freeze it doesn't throws any exceptions, it just stays waiting.
2. The request is done correctly. The response is received by Okhttp but it doesn't print the content. After that the same behaviour as before, it just stays there waiting.

This is the log of the response, it only has entries generated by okhttp and by the system. It sometimes stops with just this log:

> com.mobileapp D/OkHttp: --> GET http://192.168.15.216:8080/analista/sincronizacion?date=2000-02-01T21%3A14%3A57 http/1.1
>   com.mobileapp D/OkHttp: Accept: application/json
>       Authorization: Bearer 1234Gasd34554.21
>       Host: 192.168.15.216:8080
>       Connection: Keep-Alive
>   com.mobileapp D/OkHttp: Accept-Encoding: gzip
>       User-Agent: okhttp/3.10.0
>   com.mobileapp D/OkHttp: --> END GET
>   com.mobileapp D/OkHttp: --> GET http://192.168.15.216:8080/analista/sincronizacion?date=2000-02-01T21%3A14%3A57 http/1.1
>   com.mobileapp D/OkHttp: Accept: application/json
>       Authorization: Bearer 1234Gasd34554.21
>       Host: 192.168.15.216:8080
>       Connection: Keep-Alive
>       Accept-Encoding: gzip
>       User-Agent: okhttp/3.10.0
>   com.mobileapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xae454660: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xae46a6b0)
>   com.mobileapp D/OkHttp: --> END GET
>   com.mobileapp D/OkHttp: --> GET http://192.168.15.216:8080/analista/sincronizacion?date=2000-02-01T21%3A14%3A57 http/1.1
>   com.mobileapp D/OkHttp: Accept: application/json
>   com.mobileapp D/OkHttp: Authorization: Bearer 1234Gasd34554.21
>       Host: 192.168.15.216:8080
>       Connection: Keep-Alive
>   com.mobileapp D/OkHttp: Accept-Encoding: gzip
>       User-Agent: okhttp/3.10.0
>   com.mobileapp D/OkHttp: --> END GET
>
> com.mobileapp D/OkHttp: <-- 200 OK http://192.168.15.216:8080/analista/sincronizacion?date=2000-02-01T21%3A14%3A57 (883ms)
>       Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
>       X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
>       X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
>   com.mobileapp D/OkHttp: Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
>       Pragma: no-cache
>       Expires: 0
>       X-Application-Context: sniim:dev:8080
>       Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
>       Transfer-Encoding: chunked
>       Date: Wed, 18 Jul 2018 21:15:23 GMT
>   07-18 21:15:23.538 3096-3405/? W/audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 33531398 , only wrote 33395042
>   07-18 21:15:43.130 29617-31676/android.process.media D/DownloadManager: [3] Starting
>   07-18 21:15:58.059 3365-3379/system_process I/ActivityManager: Waited long enough for: ServiceRecord{653b062 u0 com.android.providers.downloads/.DownloadService}
>   07-18 21:16:08.328 1262-1295/? D/hwcomposer: hw_composer sent 2642 syncs in 60s
>   07-18 21:16:53.320 3938-3949/com.android.phone I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 11302(724KB) AllocSpace objects, 5(80KB) LOS objects, 42% free, 1400KB/2MB, paused 6.152ms total 27.107ms
>   07-18 21:17:08.336 1262-1295/? D/hwcomposer: hw_composer sent 3152 syncs in 60s
>   07-18 21:18:01.841 29617-31676/android.process.media W/DownloadManager: [3] Stop requested with status HTTP_DATA_ERROR: Failed reading response: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
>   07-18 21:18:01.842 29617-31676/android.process.media D/DownloadManager: [3] Finished with status WAITING_TO_RETRY
>   07-18 21:18:08.328 1262-1295/? D/hwcomposer: hw_composer sent 3123 syncs in 60s

After that log it sometimes passes onto the next one:

> Date: Wed, 18 Jul 2018 21:25:56 GMT
>   07-18 16:25:56.981 12090-12113/com.kaiten.samz.sniimappV3 D/OkHttp: {"diasFestivos":[{"id":1,"dia":"2000-01-02"},{"id":2,"dia":"2000-01-08"},{"id":3,"dia":"2000-01-09"},{"id":4,"dia":"2000-01-15"},{"id":5,"dia":"2000-01-16"}, 
>   ...
>   ...
>   ...
>   {"id":21061768,"descripcion":"Zacapoaxtla","abrev":"Zacapoaxtla","clvAnt":"1768.0","latitud":null,"longitud":null,"cotiza":false,"tipoPunto":{"id":2,
>
> read: Unexpected EOF!

The ResponseBody is made so it receives a string (due to some other processing required), so it shouldn't have any problems regarding deserialization.

Comment: Try increasing read timeout

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these in your code.

```
okhttp3.OkHttpClient client = new okhttp3.OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES) // Change it as per your requirement
                .readTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)// Change it as per your requirement
                .writeTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)// Change it as per your requirement
                .build();
```

Set above as client to retrofit.